# Interpolating between two fourier transforms over time

Tags: python, numpy, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm a musician and I'm making a script that takes a wave file and snaps each of its frequencies from the fourier transforms to the nearest musical harmonic. Thanks to help from another question I posted here, that part works, but what I need to do now is make it so throughout the sound wave it tunes one frequency at a time so that at the beginning of the output it sounds the same as the input, and by the end it sounds like an instrument.

If I just wanted them to fade into each other then that would be easy, I could just crossfade in audacity or take a weighted average of the original fourier transform and the output one, but what I want to do instead is tune one frequency at a time. This means that at 50% of the way through the output, 50% of the frequencies have been snapped to the nearest harmonic and the other 50% are untouched. How could I accomplish this without computing every single sample of the output individually?

Also, I was thinking of reducing the MAX_HARMONIC over time as well but it would have a similar problem.

This is the sample I'm testing with (rename it to missile.wav):
https://my.mixtape.moe/iltlos.wav

Here is the script so far:

```
import struct
import wave
import numpy as np


# import data from wave
wav_file = wave.open("missile.wav", 'r')
num_samples = wav_file.getnframes()
sampling_rate = wav_file.getframerate() / 2
data = wav_file.readframes(num_samples)
wav_file.close()

data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), data)
data = np.array(data)

# fast fourier transform makes an array of the frequencies of sine waves that comprise the sound
data_fft = np.fft.rfft(data)


# the higher MAX_HARMONIC is, the more it sounds like the original, 
# the lower it is, the more it sounds like an instrument
MAX_HARMONIC = 2

# generate list of ratios that can be used for tuning (not octave reduced)
valid_ratios = []
for i in range(1, MAX_HARMONIC + 1):
    for j in range(1, MAX_HARMONIC + 1):
        if i % 2 != 0 and j % 2 != 0:
            valid_ratios.append(i/float(j))
            valid_ratios.append(j/float(i))


# remove dupes
valid_ratios = list(set(valid_ratios))


# find all the frequencies with the valid ratios
valid_frequencies = []
multiple = 2
while(multiple < num_samples / 2):
    multiple *= 2

    for ratio in valid_ratios:
        frequency = ratio * multiple

        if frequency < num_samples / 2:
            valid_frequencies.append(frequency)



# remove dupes and sort and turn into a numpy array
valid_frequencies = np.sort(np.array(list(set(valid_frequencies))))


# bin the data_fft into the nearest valid frequency
valid_frequencies = valid_frequencies.astype(np.int64)
boundaries = np.concatenate([[0], np.round(np.sqrt(0.25 + valid_frequencies[:-1] * valid_frequencies[1:])).astype(np.int64)])
select = np.abs(data_fft) > 1
filtered_data_fft = np.zeros_like(data_fft)
filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies] = np.add.reduceat(np.where(select, data_fft, 0), boundaries)


# do the inverse fourier transform to get a sound wave back
recovered_signal = np.fft.irfft(filtered_data_fft)

# write sound wave to wave file
comptype="NONE"
compname="not compressed"
nchannels=1
sampwidth=2

wav_file=wave.open("missile_output.wav", 'w')
wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, int(sampling_rate), num_samples, comptype, compname))

for s in recovered_signal:
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', s))

wav_file.close()
```

Comment: I don't think it's going to be easy to get this time-varying behaviour via a single FFT.  It's more likely you'll need multiple overlapping FFTs (basically the "short-time Fourier Transform" STFT).  More generally, this use-case sounds a lot like the essence of a [phase vocoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder).  This is basically a signal processing problem rather than a coding problem, so I suspect you'd get more useful answers on https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try there!

Comment: side note: use `scipy.io.wavfile` its faster and more robust